# Why do we want a big parallelism?

Tags: multithreading

I would really like to know why we want the ratio T1/T_infinity (the parallelism) to be big?

Comment: Can you give a little more context ?

Comment: @cnicutar: The terminology seems to be used e.g. here: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-22-advanced-topics/6_046J2005L22.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that you can parallelise the implementation of the algorithm, and achieve a big speedup!

That ratio describes how much speedup you'd get if you used an infinite number of processors compared to just one processor.  So it's an upper bound on how much speedup you'll get with a non-infinite number of processors.

*See also: [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_Law)*.